# How to Return to an already open application when a user tries to open a new instance if same version?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I want to open up an existing instance if my program is already running only if its running the same version.  I noticed that this question was asked for only if the name exists, but what if the version is older, I just want to notify the user that an older version is still running, "please remove older version before starting this version."

The other link is this one:
[Return to an already open application when a user tries to open a new instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94274/return-to-an-already-open-application-when-a-user-tries-to-open-a-new-instance)  but they don't talk about closing an instance if an older or newer version is detected.

Comment: This can't be a real problem, Windows doesn't allow overwriting the EXE of a running process.

Comment: @Hans Passant: I don't think that's what the OP is trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a variant of the method which I describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7777798/49241) and that described [here](http://sanity-free.org/143/csharp_dotnet_single_instance_application.html) using [System.Threading.Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx).

I guess you could have two mutex's. Mutex A named by a GUID and mutex B named by GUID and version number.

Your new instance can first check for mutex A on start up. If mutex A does not exist, then no other version is running. If mutex A exists then *some* other version is running.

The new instance can then check for existence of mutex B, using it's own version number. If B does exist, then the other instance is the same version as the new instance, if B doesn't exist, then some other version is running.

Comment: Could you give a code example?  I have an open source project that I need to detect if a previous version is already running or detect if its the current or later release and do different things.

Comment: Have a look at the second link (http://sanity-free.org/143/csharp_dotnet_single_instance_application.html). It has code examples of how to use a mutex.

Answer (score 1):

What about making your application a singleton, thereby restricting it to a single instance.

Comment: The OP states that richer behaviour is required, i.e. the new instance should simply delegate to the current instance if the versions are the same, but give a notification regarding versioning when the versions are different.

Answer (score 1):

If an older version is already deployed then you may not be able to change the code in it. In  which case you can simply get the [currently running](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f3ys1f9.aspx) processes and look for the exe name of your older version app and then [investigate the version number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187999/how-do-i-get-the-version-of-an-assembly-without-loading-it). If its an older version then you can do whatever you want.

If you want to build this functionality for future then you can create a [namedpipe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085.aspx) and a new running app will try to connect to that pipe to get the latest version.